# Definition of continuity at a point: can we take only sequences of distinct members?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

> **Q.** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Fix $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f$ satisfies property: given any sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ of *distinct terms* converging to $a$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(a)$. Can we conclude that $f$ is continuous at $a$?

Here I am considering only those sequences $\{x_n\}$ converging to $a$ such that $x_n\neq x_m$ for $n\neq m$. That means, I am not allowing any single repetition. Can we still proceed to show that $f$ is continuous at $a$?

**My way** Consider arbitrary sequence $\{y_n\}$ converging to $a$. We show that $f(y_n)$ converges to $f(a)$.

**Aim:** To produce a sequence $\{y_n'\}$ such that (i) $y_n'$ converges to same point at which $\{ y_n\}$ converges. (ii) All terms of $\{y_n'\}$ are distinct.

This is done with the following.

Start with $y_1$; so put $y_1':=y_1$.

Take $y_2'=y_2+\frac{1}{n_1}$ for suitable $n_1>1$ so that $y_2'\neq y_1'$.

Take $y_3'=y_3+\frac{1}{n_2}$ for suitable $n_2>n_1$ so that $y_3'\notin \{ y_1',y_2'\}$.

Continue this process. Then we get desired sequence as in Aim.

By assumption, $f(y_n')$ converges to $f(a)$.

How to show now that $f(y_n)$ converges to $f(a)$?

Is this approach OK, or is there any other way for the above question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this works, since the fact that your sequence $y'_i$ has the property that $f(y'_i)\to f(a)$ doesn't seem to tell you anything about $f(y_i)$.

I think the right way to consider subsequences. If $f(y_i)\not\to f(a)$, show that  there must be some subsequence $y_{i_j}$ satisfying $f(y_{i_j})\to b$ for some $b\neq f(a)$ (possibly $b=\infty$ or $b=-\infty$). Now show that you can find a subsequence of the subsequence whose terms are all distinct.